# OutOfMemoryException - WCF services

Tags: c#, .net, string, wcf, out-of-memory

I have a WCF (C#) project published, and I am facing "OutOfMemoryException" problems. The DLLs are built with `Any CPU`. AppPool memory settings are set to 0 (means there is no limit).
I have around 1500 requests per minute constantly and around 100 other requests per minute. The project uses EntityFramework. There is caching in the application (it is a dictionary)

I did some troubleshooting to try to find out the problem, but it is not clear yet. I tried to compute the total memory used (by calling `GC.GetTotalMemory(false)`) and the size of the cache list. While getting the OOM exceptions the cache size is around 7 MB (2500 objects of 30 KB each) and total memory used is varying between 600 MB to 1.5 GB.

So it is obvious that the memory is not full and the resources are being cleared regularly by the `GarbageCollector` (the size of memory is not increased all the time). Thus, the OOM exception is not because the memory is full.

Mainly I am seeing in the logs OOM exceptions when serializing objects to JSON (I am using Newtonsoft) or applying some operations on strings (concatenation, replace, Regexreplace, ...), here are some examples of the exceptions:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
at System.Text.StringBuilder.ExpandByABlock(Int32 minBlockCharCount)
at System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(Char* value, Int32 valueCount)
at System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(String value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 count)
at System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexReplacement.Replace(Regex regex, String input, Int32 count, Int32 startat)
at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(String input, String replacement, Int32 count, Int32 startat)
at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(String input, String replacement)
at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(String input, String pattern, String replacement)
```

and

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
at System.String.ReplaceInternal(String oldValue, String newValue)
at System.String.Replace(String oldValue, String newValue)
```

Any ideas or suggestions on what can be done to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Verify the bitness of the process. You'll find that it's 32 bit.

Comment: How can I get the bitness? The DLL are built with "Any CPU" settings and the server is running Windows server 2012 x64. So the normal behavior is 64 for the DLLs!

Comment: DLLs take the bitness of the hosting process. Use Process Explorer to find out, or Response.Write(IntPtr.Size).

Comment: @usr, I used IntPrt.Size on the production server just now, and it is returning 4, which means the DLLs are running as 32 bit. As well, the worker process for IIS is running as 32 bit application. I guess what I need to do is to force IIS to run as 64 bit and my problem will be solved? What is the impact of running the DLLs as 32 bit? P.S. I am seeing the total memory used sometimes exceed the 2GB (which is the max for 32 bit DLLs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing address space fragmentation on 32 bit. The maximum available address space depends on the OS and exe, cold be 2,3 or 4 GB.

Run the IIS worker process as 64 bit so that your AnyCPU DLL can take advantage of that.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. The DLLs are working now in 64 bit mode.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that problem is with long strings. Probably `StringBuilder` want extend memory when it append new content. I' not sure but when this operation take place; `StringBuilder` try double size. I beleve that CLR can't allocate object with size bigger then 2GB and that why it throws `OutOfMemoryException`

Comment: "`ExpandByABlock`": StringBuilder uses small blocks in later framework versions.

Comment: I had this in mind, but I am sure that I don't have object/strings with 2GB size. For example the first exception pasted in the question has 10 KB as size, and the replace function is called to  remove some words (replace them by empty). So I am not sure this the problem !

Comment: Maybe you can tray to run some profiling tool and focus on memory measurement. Another possibility is that tree you are trying serialize in fact is graph with some circular references

Comment: @Mostafa Try set json serializer with options PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects